# Problem with debugging python modules in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have the following directory structure for my python practice project:

```
.
├── data
├── ds-and-algo
├── exercises
|   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── armstrong_number.py
│   ├── extract_digits.py
├── output
```

The `extract_digits.py` looks something like this:

```py
def extract_digits(n):
    pass
```

In the `armstrong_number.py` I have the following:

```py
from .extract_digits import extract_digits
```

From root project directory if I run

```sh
python exercises/armstrong_number.py
```

I get `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named exercises`

Running the following commad with `-m` flag resolves the error:

```sh
python -m exercises.armstrong_number
```

However using `VSCode` in order to debug the file, I have the following debug config `launch.json`:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "module": "exercises.${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH":"${workspaceRoot}"}
        }
    ]
}
```

However this has a few problems:

1) For a different folder, for e.g. `ds-and-algo`, I have to manually edit the module entry in the launch.json file debug configuration to

```
"module" : "ds-and-algo.${fileBaseNameNoExtension}"
```

In case I have nested folder configuration like:

```
exercises
├── tough
|   | __init__.py
|   ├──ex1.py
|   ├──ex2.py
├── easy
```

I again have to manually edit the debug config in `launch.json` file to: (considering the case for the sub-folder `tough`)

```
"module": "exercises.tough.${fileBaseNameNoExtension}"
```

I need to implement a general case where depending on the file being debugged, the `"module"` entry in the `launch.json` file should be:

`"module": "folder1.folder2.folder3.....foldern.script"`

Just like `fileBaseNameNoExtension`, `VSCode` has [some other predefined variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference):

One of the variables is `relativeFile`, which is the path of the current opened file relative to `workspaceFolder`
So for the file `ex1.py`, the variable `relativeFile` will be `exercises/tough/ex1.py`.

I need to manipulate this string and convert this to `exercises.tough.ex1`, which is trivial if I can write and execute bash command inside the `"module"` entry in `launch.json` file. But I am unable to do that. However, the link [predefined variables in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) has a section on **Command variables**, which states:

*if the predefined variables from above are not sufficient, you can use any VS Code command as a variable through the **${command:commandID}** syntax.*

This link has a bunch of other information that may be helpful. I am no expert in python, and definitely don't know any javascript, if that is what is required to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error: `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named exercises`.

Using the following files

`exercises/extract_digits.py`

```
def extract_digits(n):
  return 10
```

`exercises/armstrong_number.py`

```
from extract_digits import extract_digits

def armstrong_number(n):
  return extract_digits(n)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
  print armstrong_number(3)
```

If you use Python3 change the print statement to: `print(armstrong_number(3))` and change the used Python interpreter.

If your current directory is the project root directory and you run

```
python exercises/armstrong_number.py
```

You get the number 10 in the console

---

In Visual Studio Code you use the wrong Launch configuration.

You are just running python programs so you should use the `Python: Current File` configuration.
`launch.json`

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
    }
  ]
}
```

1. Open the example py file you want to run/debug, in whatever directory it is.
2. Or make it the current file
3. Select the Debug Side Bar
4. Select the `Python: Current File` configuration
5. Click the "green" triangle.

Now a complicated command is constructed and run. It will set the CWD to the directory of the current file and start the debugger on the current file.

---

If you **really** need the module launch you can use a `Multi-Root Workspace` in VSC and have a separate configured `launch.json` for each of the root directories

---

If you want to use the `${command:commandID}` syntax you can construct a simple extension that uses the `activeTextEditor` and construct a string based on the file name

---

**Edit**

Another option is to use Multiple Launch configurations.

I have removed the properties where the default value works or that are not used.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Exercise",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "module": "exercises.${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
    },
    {
      "name": "Exercise.Easy",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "module": "exercises.easy.${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
    },
    {
      "name": "DS",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "module": "ds.${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
    }
  ]
}
```

---

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) to get this relative directory with dot separator.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Module CmdVar",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "module": "${command:extension.commandvariable.file.relativeDirDots}.${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: My armstrong_number.py has a dot (.) before the import module like this:```python from .extract_digits import extract_digits ```, So, ```python exercises/armstrong_number.py```,gives the following error:
```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.extract_digits'; '__main__' is not a package
```I don't want them to act like indiv scripts but a module part of a single project workspace. I do use the Current file config, but that's for one-off scripts. Not inside a project.```activeTextEditor``` and ```${command:commandID}``` seem like what I really need. But I am not really sure how.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Another option is: Multiple Launch configurations. See my edit

Comment: This really works! Thanks! I think this is a really new extension, since I had to update vscode from 1.36 to 1.37, to be able to install this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about running bash scripts, although if it's possible to run JavaScript in the file, `"ds-and-algo.(${fileBaseNameNoExtension}).split('/').join('.')"` should do the trick.

Actually, the reason you need the `-m` flag at all is because you don't have `__init__.py` files in your folders. These files may be empty, but they're used by python to identify a module structure and thus allow nested and relative imports. I hope adding those files should allow you to just run `python exercises/armstrong_number.py` or `python ds-and-algo/tough/ex1.py`

Comment: I already have ```__init__.py``` file in the folders. I am sorry I forgot to mention that in the tree structure. I have made the edit now. I tried the ```split``` and ```join``` command in the module entry of the ```launch.json``` file.
I edited the file to have 
``` 
"module": "${relativePath}.split('/').join('.')" ```
but I think it definitely executes bash to evaluate the expression as I got the following error:
```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to specify in your `launch.json` that you want it to calculate what the module you want to debug is. This is because it's technically impossible to get right 100% of the time due to namespace packages letting any directory represent a package. Your best option is to create separate debug configurations per example you want to run in your `launch.json` (you can have as many as you want). If doing that by hand is too tedious you could write a Python script to generate your `launch.json` for you.

Comment: Is there a way I can run a python script as a task automatically in VSCode, before I start debugging? Basically I would want the ```module``` entry in the ```launch.json``` file to be different in each. I think I need to read up on namespace packages to really understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia not that I'm aware of. You could write a Python script and set up a task for it so that you can easily run it from within VS Code. And depending on how much effort you want to put into it you could make a daemon process with file watchers to automatically detect when a change occurs to then automatically update `launch.json`. But that might be a bit too much work for a one-off problem. :)