# vscode python launch 'current file' as module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to find a way to give current file as argument for module. I couldn't find it anywhere so I'm trying stackoverflow

```
{
    "name": "Python: Synapse",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "projFolder.targetModule",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

Manually specifying the module argument such as above example, works. But thinking of doing that for every each file wanted me to automate it. I've tried ${file}, but it gives the file path not the module. So it didn't work. How can I launch current current file as module?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392698/problem-with-debugging-python-modules-in-vscode

Comment: Yes thank you. The answer solved my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with debugging python modules in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392698/problem-with-debugging-python-modules-in-vscode)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ps: answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57416114/6088796, but I modify a litter

add something like this to your launch.json, but if you want to run multi-module(in a different place, the only way you can do is using multi configuration, or use a plugin(see below)

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "yourmodule.${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "stopOnEntry": true
        },
```

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) to get this relative directory with dot separator.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Module CmdVar",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "module": "${command:extension.commandvariable.file.relativeDirDots}.${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: there is a combined command: `"module": "${command:extension.commandvariable.file.relativeFileDotsNoExtension}",`